# How to make an animation/transition with the width of a node in javafx?

Tags: java, animation, javafx, transition

I want to make an animation with the "width" of my node.

In this case my node is a "AnchorPane".

I try to make a navigation drawer in javafx.

**there is no property "width Property ()"?**

```
new Key Value (node.width Property (), 1, WEB_EASE)
```

`node.widthProperty().getValue(`)  not found

My code:

```
public void changeWidth(final Node node, double width) {
    this.node = node;
    this.timeline = TimelineBuilder.create()
        .keyFrames(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(20),    
                new KeyValue(    going here?   , width, WEB_EASE)
            )
        )
        .build();

    setCycleDuration(Duration.seconds(5));
    setDelay(Duration.seconds(0));
}
```

Example with "opacity" property:

```
new KeyValue(node.opacityProperty(), 1, WEB_EASE)
```

My class ConfigAnimationViewPane:

```
public class ConfigAnimationViewPane extends Transition {
    protected static final Interpolator WEB_EASE = Interpolator.EASE_BOTH;
    protected AnchorPane node;
    protected Timeline timeline;
    private boolean oldCache = false;
    private CacheHint oldCacheHint = CacheHint.DEFAULT;
    private final boolean useCache = true;



    /**
     * Called when the animation is starting
     */
    protected void starting() {
        if (useCache) {
            oldCache = node.isCache();
            oldCacheHint = node.getCacheHint();
            node.setCache(true);
            node.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the animation is stopping
     */
    protected void stopping() {
        if (useCache) {
            node.setCache(oldCache);
            node.setCacheHint(oldCacheHint);
        }
    }

    @Override protected void interpolate(double d) {
        timeline.playFrom(Duration.seconds(d));
        timeline.stop();
    }

}
```

This is mi controller:

Move the menu to the left (the occult)

```
LeftTransition leftTransition = new LeftTransition();
                leftTransition.OpenMenu(list1);
                leftTransition.play();
```

Here I want to put my size "AnchorPane".
(Set the width of my "anchorpane")

```
 /*ViewPaneTransition paneTransition = new ViewPaneTransition();
            paneTransition.CloseMenu(viewPane, width );
            paneTransition.play();*/
```

Comment: ah what? can't you do this? `changeWidth(final Pane node, double width) {` ?? there you will get `PrefWidthProperty` **OR** maintain your Node and use `node.prefWidth(-1);` use a double binder to get your width in successions.

Comment: the property or method "Pref Width Property ()" does not exist.

Comment: hmm i guess im high then :) .... [Pane extends Region, and ...](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#prefWidthProperty--)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void changeWidth(final Pane/*Region*/ node, double width) {//its a Pane or Regions
    this.node = node;
    this.timeline = TimelineBuilder.create()
        .keyFrames(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(20),    
                new KeyValue(    going here?   , width, WEB_EASE)
            )
        )
        .build();

    setCycleDuration(Duration.seconds(5));
    setDelay(Duration.seconds(0));
}
```

> In this case my node is a "AnchorPane".

your `AnchorPane` is a subclass or `Pane`, let your wrappers or methods take in `Pane` or their respective class

Comment: Node I want to handle this in my window. this within my parent node.

Comment: i do not get your comment, show all your good here Sir, honestly if you just copy paste and did as i said you will come back with thank yous, but if its returned as parent you can cast it to AnchorPane and place it in your method @VipPunkJoshersDroopy

Comment: I try to make a navigation drawer in javafx. 

I want to increase the size of anchorpane, paneTransition.Close Menu (view Pane, width),

 @Elltz.

Comment: It doesn't compile at all under Java 9 and is not complete, see my answer. - setCycleDuration is protected and should not be used, Duration.seconds(5) should be passed to the keyFrame, timeline.start is not called.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working example for java 9. It changes both the width and the height (just remove the height line if you don't need it)

The widthProperty is readOnly so yo have to set either maxWidth or minWidth switch the case you need.
the delay duration on timeline is 0 by default, no need to set it, and the cycleduration is computed from the keyframes durations.

```
public void changeSize(final Pane pane, double width, double height) {
    Duration cycleDuration = Duration.millis(500);
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(cycleDuration,
                    new KeyValue(pane.maxWidthProperty(),width,Interpolator.EASE_BOTH)),
            new KeyFrame(cycleDuration,
                    new KeyValue(pane.maxHeightProperty(),height,Interpolator.EASE_BOTH))
            );

    timeline.play();
    timeline.setOnFinished(event->{
       /* insert code here if you need */
    });
}
```